# SqlDependency.Start() gives error Cannot attach the file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\EduTech.mdf' as database 'EduTech'

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to start `sql` dependency but it gives me the following error:

> Cannot attach the file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\EduTech.mdf' as database 'EduTech'.

Full error details follow:

> Cannot attach the file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\EduTech.mdf' as database 'EduTech'.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>   Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot attach the file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\EduTech.mdf' as database 'EduTech'.
>   Source Error: Line 25: BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
>   Line 26: SqlDependency.Stop(con);
>   Line 27: SqlDependency.Start(con);
>   Line 28: }
>   Line 29: protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
>   stack trace[SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot attach the file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\EduTech.mdf' as database 'EduTech'.]

Here's what my connection string looks like:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\EduTech.mdf;Initial Catalog=EduTech;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I'm using it in my controller as follows:

```
string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

When I remove the line `SqlDependency.start()` the app runs perfectly fine.

Comment: Cannot attach the file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\EduTech.mdf' as database 'EduTech'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot attach the file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\EduTech.mdf' as database 'EduTech'.

Source Error:

Comment: Line 25:             BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
Line 26:             SqlDependency.Stop(con);
Line 27:             SqlDependency.Start(con);
Line 28:         }
Line 29:         protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: stack trace[SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot attach the file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\EduTech.mdf' as database 'EduTech'.]

Comment: please don't comment additional information, but edit your original post instead - also without you providing us code, we can not take a look at your code to see what's wrong.

Comment: i was unable to put the stack trace in question itself so  i commented

Comment: @FranzGleichmann let me know if you need more details of my code

Comment: Hi dharav. I've updated your question so at to include the error details that you added in comments. I also changed formatting to make the question clearer and to better organize the information in it. Please see [the editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting to help with this in the future. Good luck!

Comment: thanks @Ortund will improve that part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved myself by replacing default connection sting to

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=W:\ongoing projects\Edutech\EduTech\App_Data\EduTech.mdf;Initial Catalog=EduTech;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

i don't know why DataDirectory doesn't work but specifying the exact location works